# Calculate the limitation:$I=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{2\pi}{\frac{\cos nx}{x+1}}\text{d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

$$I=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{2\pi}{\frac{\cos nx}{x+1}}\text{d}x
$$

the answer is 0. This is what I've done so far.

$$ \begin{split}
\int_0^{2\pi}{\frac{\cos nx}{x+1}}\text{d}x&=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{2\pi}{\frac{1}{x+1}}\text{d}\left( \sin nx \right)\\
&=\left. \frac{\sin nx}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{1+x} \right|_{0}^{2\pi}+\int_0^{2\pi}{\frac{\sin nx}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{\left( 1+x \right) ^2}}\text{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}{\frac{\sin nx}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{\left( 1+x \right) ^2}}\text{d}x  
\end{split}$$

Comment: Is it just me, or is integration just beautiful to look at...?

Comment: @user477343 how to go on? Do  we  need  to use  any inequality?

Comment: Why don't you try integration by parts two times to be able to compute then integral and then apply the limit?

Comment: @GBes thank you for your hint

Comment: Head to @IsaacBrowne 's answer below $\downarrow$ for an inequality-like approach.

Comment: It is enough to invoke the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma).

Answer (score 6):

Following your intuition, an inequality is useful at the point you got to, namely $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$ Using that, we have
$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin(nx)}{(1+x)^2}dx\right| \leq\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}dx=\frac{1}{n}\frac{-1}{x+1}\bigg|_0^{2\pi}=\frac{1}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2\pi+1}\right)<\frac{1}{n}$$
Now letting $n$ go to infinity we get
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |I| <\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$$
So $I=0$

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to approach this.

A less common, but good general technique to know, is to apply Bonnet's second mean value theorem for integrals which states that if $f$ is integrable and $g$ is decreasing then there exists $\xi \in [a,b]$ such that

$$\int_a^b f(x) g(x) \, dx = g(a) \int_a^\xi f(x) \, dx.$$

Hence,

$$\left|\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos nx}{x+1} \,dx \right| = \frac{1}{1+0}\left|\int_0^{\xi}\cos nx \,dx \right| = \frac{|\sin n\xi - \sin 0|}{n} \leqslant \frac{1}{n} $$

and we see that the limit is $0$.

Comment: @tjujystsll: You're welcome.  This is generally true by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma: $\lim_{\alpha \to \infty} \int_a^b f(x) \cos \alpha x \,dx = 0$ for any integrable function $f$.

Comment: Ok,thanks for your guidance.I learn a lot from your solution.